# ¿como puedo pintar los datos que me trae el logger en un archivo txt?

Tags: java-ee

Hola estoy creando un clase donde estoy extrayendo datos de una base de datos pero los datos los estoy pintando en un logger. quisiera me ayuden para que en lugar de pintarlo en el logger, se cree un txt y pintarlo en el ese archivo. lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente.

```
package com.bbva.mjia.batch.writer;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;

import com.bbva.mjia.batch.writer.Writer;

public class Writer implements ItemWriter<Map<String, Object>>{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Writer.class);

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Map<String, Object>> chunk) throws Exception {
        for(Map<String,Object>mapa:chunk){
            System.out.println(mapa.toString());
            LOGGER.info(mapa.toString());



        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué librería de logging estás usando por debajo? Porque SL4J es una capa de abstracción y lo que usas realmente puede ser Log4J, Logback... y la respuesta cambiará un poco en función de tu respuesta

Comment: no estoy usando una librería loggin bueno no por el momento

Answer (score 0):

Si no tienes en tu classpath alguna librería de logging, SLFJ, tal y como dice su documentación, no hará nada: `SINCE 1.6.0 If no binding is found on the class path, then SLF4J will default to a no-operation implementation.` [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

Si usases Log4J, debes:

- Descargarte el JAR de [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html) e inclúyelo en el classpath de tu proyecto
- En alguna carpeta que forme parte del código fuente de tu proyecto, crea un fichero llamado log4j2.properties con esta configuración de ejemplo:

  status = error
  name = PropertiesConfig

  property.filename = \output.log

  filters = threshold

  filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
  filter.threshold.level = debug

  appenders = rolling

  appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
  appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
  appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
  appender.rolling.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
  appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
  appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
  appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
  appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
  appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
  appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
  appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
  appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
  appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
  appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20

  loggers = rolling

  logger.rolling.name = com.bbva.mjia.batch.writer
  logger.rolling.level = debug
  logger.rolling.additivity = false
  logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile

Con este debería serte suficiente para ver que los logs que generas se escriben en el fichero que has especificado en esas propiedades.